# 404 Error on Image Transforms

Tags: assets, control-panel, php

Transformed Images are failing to load with a `404 error`  For example:

`http://mysite.com/index.php?p=cpresources/transforms/382&x=v0nGRK3Qr`

This happened after I swapped the db.  So, everything had previously been working.

Also:

- My images reside `/public_html/mysite/img/posts/`
- BUT, `Update Asset Indexes` generates `The path of your source "Main Post Image" appears to be invalid` And, none of the images load when I try to view Assets in cp.
- I can access the image from the `public URL` to the assets is `http://www.mysite.com/img/posts`.  And, I can access the original uploaded images here.
- I **assume** the path to my images (which I understand can be different from the URL) is the problem.
- Path is current set to /mysite/img/posts/'.  I have tried multiple permutations - nothing seems to work.

Help/Thanks

Comment: I tried adding `generateTransformsBeforePageLoad` to `general.php`.   But, I still get a 404 error and the image transforms do not load.

Comment: Oh, I tried a fresh re-install of Craft and the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/mysite/img/posts/` is an absolute path pointing to the root of your drive mount.

You probably just need to make it relative.  i.e. either `mysite/img/posts` or `./mysite/img/posts`.

Comment: Nope.  I have tried every which freaking way.

Comment: Incredible.  It was a freaking period.   `./img/posts/` worked.  Held up by a freaking "."  Ugh.  Thanks.